# Can I edit code during push to main repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, push

I'm using mercurial control version for my project in windows using tortoisHg.
I would like to know what happens when I editing code during pushing to server? can it make any unwanted issues on my repository?

Comment: Your description of the scenario is not clear. Do you mean editing files in the repository while a push is running? If so - not problem. The push is not affected by changes to the working directory. Please add details.

Comment: Yes I mean `editing files in the repository while a push is running`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, you can keep editing while the push is running. The push collects your changesets from the .hg folder (metadata) and is not affected by your editing of the files.

Note - to be safe, **don't** commit while the push is running.